# reading files in google cloud machine learning

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I tried to run [tensorflow-wavenet](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet) on the google cloud ml-engine with `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training` but the cloud job crashed when it was trying to read the json configuration file:

```
with open(args.wavenet_params, 'r') as f:
   wavenet_params = json.load(f)
```

`arg.wavenet_params` is simply a file path to a json file which I uploaded to the google cloud storage bucket. The file path looks like this: `gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILE_PATH.json`.

I double-checked that the file path is correct and I'm sure that this part is responsible for the crash since I commented out everything else.

The crash log file doesn't give much information about what has happened:

```
Module raised an exception for failing to call a subprocess Command '['python', '-m', u'gcwavenet.train', u'--data_dir', u'gs://wavenet-test-data/VCTK-Corpus-Small/', u'--logdir_root', u'gs://wavenet-test-data//gcwavenet10/logs']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I replaced `wavenet_params = json.load(f)` by `f.close()` and I still get the same result.

Everything works when I run it locally with `gcloud ml-engine local train`.

I think the problem is with reading files with `gcloud ml-engine` in general or that I can't access the google cloud bucket from within a python file with `gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILE_PATH`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41633748/1399222, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40396552/1399222

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python's `open` function cannot read files from GCS. You will need to use a library capable of doing so. TensorFlow includes one such library:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

with file_io.FileIO(args.wavenet_params, 'r') as f:
  wavenet_params = json.load(f)
```

Comment: How can I attach my json with permission credentials to the function in order to access a private bucket?

Comment: You can set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable. However, doing that in CMLE may be tricky. You can try setting os.env['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] before importing tensorflow, but I'm not sure that will work. You can also write a wrapper script that sets the environment variable and then runs your real script as a subprocess.

Comment: I also found `tf.contrib.cloud.configure_gcs`. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cloud/configure_gcs

Comment: As well as https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cloud/ConfigureGcsHook