# saving python PIL image from Google cloud datalab to Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, python-imaging-library, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to save a PIL image to google cloud storage from Datalab.

```
from PIL import Image
out_image = Image.open( StringIO( gs_buck_obj.read_stream() ) )

# run through cloud vision api and do some stuff
....

my_file = StringIO()
out_image.save(my_file , "PNG")
**This is where I am not sure what to do but have tried next line
gs_buck_obj_out.write_stream(my_file.getvalue(), 'text/plain')
```

Answer (score 2):

> This stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396552/google-storage-gs-wrapper-file-input-out-for-cloud-ml) raises the question of a python `open` wrapper for all `gs://` paths. A very clean solution lies in using the `file_io` module in `tensorflow`.

Example:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io.file_io import FileIO

with FileIO('gs://my-bucket/20180101/my-file.txt', 'r') as f:
   print(f.readlines()) # works

with FileIO('gs://my-bucket/20180101/my-file.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('I love roti prata.') # works

with FileIO('my-file.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('I love palak paneer.') 
   # also works with local files in reading and writing
```

**As stated by this [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/08/new-version-of-cloud-datalab-jupyter-meets-tensorflow-cloud-meets-local-deployment), Cloud Datalab does supports tensorflow.** And `FileIO` supports `'wb'` (*write byte*) mode. So a solution to your problem would be

```
with FileIO('out_image.png', 'wb') as f:
    out_image.save(f, "PNG")
```

Comment: A note about this solution: it only seems useful for App Engine Flexible Environment because `tensorflow` relies on C libraries which can't be installed in Standard Environment.   Am I missing something?