# Reading data from bucket in Google ml-engine (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am having issues reading data from a bucket hosted by Google.
I have a bucket containing ~1000 files I need to access, held at (for example)
  gs://my-bucket/data

Using gsutil from the command line or other of Google's Python API clients I can access the data in the bucket, however importing these APIs is not supported by default on google-cloud-ml-engine.

I need a way to access both the data and the names of the files, either with a default python library (i.e. os) or using tensorflow. I know tensorflow has this functionality built in somewhere, it has been hard for me to find

Ideally I am looking for replacements for one command such as os.listdir() and another for open()

```
train_data = [read_training_data(filename) for filename in os.listdir('gs://my-bucket/data/')]
```

Where read_training_data uses a tensorflow reader object

Thanks for any help! ( Also p.s. my data is binary )

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to read data into memory, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799952/1399222) has the details you need, namely, to use the [file_io](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py) module.

That said, you might want to consider using built-in reading mechanisms for TensorFlow as they can be more performant.

Information on reading can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data). The latest and greatest (but not yet part of official "core" TensorFlow) is the Dataset API (more info [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)).

Some things to keep in mind:

- Are you using a format TensorFlow can read? Can it be converted to that format?
- Is the overhead of "feeding" high enough to affect training performance?
- Is the training set too big to fit in memory?

If the answer is yes to one or more of the questions, especially the latter two, consider using readers.

Comment: here is a concrete example how to write a file (it is straightforward to modify it for reading but note that the `model` parameter is mandatory): https://stackoverflow.com/a/43242029/288875

Comment: I’m not sure how that applies.  Do you mean wrap the gs: entries in pickle? What is pickle?

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth.  I also had problems reading files, in particular binary files from google cloud storage inside a datalab notebook.  The first way I managed to do it was by copying files using gs-utils to my local filesystem and using tensorflow to read the files normally.   This is demonstrated here after the file copy was done.

Here is my setup cell

```
import math
import shutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format
```

Here is a cell for reading the file locally as a sanity check.

```
# this works for reading local file
audio_binary_local = tf.read_file("100852.mp3")
waveform = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(audio_binary_local, file_format='mp3', 
samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=2)
# this will show that it has two channels of data
with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(waveform)
    print (result)
```

Here is reading the file from gs: directly as a binary file.

```
# this works for remote files in gs:
gsfilename = 'gs://proj-getting-started/UrbanSound/data/air_conditioner/100852.mp3'
# python 2
#audio_binary_remote = tf.gfile.Open(gsfilename).read()
# python 3
audio_binary_remote = tf.gfile.Open(gsfilename, 'rb').read()
waveform = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(audio_binary_remote, file_format='mp3', samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=2)
# this will show that it has two channels of data
with tf.Session() as sess:
  result = sess.run(waveform)
  print (result)
```