# Loading images in cloud ml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

This is main code which works on CPU machine. It loads all images and masks from folders, resizes them, and save as 2 numpy arrays.

```
from skimage.transform import resize as imresize
from skimage.io import imread


def create_data(dir_input, img_size):

    img_files = sorted(glob(dir_input + '/images/*.jpg'))
    mask_files = sorted(glob(dir_input + '/masks/*.png'))

    X = []
    Y = []

    for img_path, mask_path in zip(img_files, mask_files):

        img = imread(img_path)
        img = imresize(img, (img_size, img_size), mode='reflect', anti_aliasing=True)

        mask = imread(mask_path)
        mask = imresize(mask, (img_size, img_size), mode='reflect', anti_aliasing=True)

        X.append(img)
        Y.append(mask)



    path_x = dir_input + '/images-{}.npy'.format(img_size)
    path_y = dir_input + '/masks-{}.npy'.format(img_size)

    np.save(path_x, np.array(X))
    np.save(path_y, np.array(Y))
```

Here is gcloud storage hierarchy

```
gs://my_bucket
|
|----inputs    
|      |----images/
|      |-----masks/
|   
|----outputs
|
|----trainer
```

`dir_input` should be `gs://my_bucket/inputs`

This doesn't work. What is the proper way to load images from that path on cloud, and save numpy array in the inputs folder?

Preferable with `skimage`, which is loaded in `setup.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Python libraries such as numpy don't natively support reading from and writing to object stores like GCS or S3. There are a few options:

- Copy the data to local disk first (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40397032/1399222)).
- Try using the GCS python SDK ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries))
- Use another library, like TensorFlow's `FileIO` abstraction. [Here's some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637685/1399222) similar to what you're trying to do (read/write numpy arrays).

The latter is particularly useful if you are using TensorFlow, but can still be used even if you are using some other framework.